# Skyrim Taste of Death Quest bug - Eola keeps attacking me!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I've been replaying Skyrim and got up to the Taste of Death (the cannibal one) and have come across a strange bug.

First time I played through, I cleared the cave without Eola but when it went to the next objective to speak to her, she kept atacking me! I managed to calm her with spells and got the next objected the kill the priest in Markarth, however, his body had already moved to the cave without me talking to him. Once again, when inside the cave, Eola attacked me and I couldn't search or feed from the priest's body.

Anyone know a fix to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

With these you have to just load the last save.